# How to fix 'Expression is unused "this::displayData" in compositeDisposable.addAll(jsonApi.getData()'?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to fetch some data from an API and display that data using retrofit and RxJava2. Am I using CompositeDisposable.addall correctly? What am I referring to when I say .subscribe {this::displayData})?

So I've attempted to replace the .subscribe{...} above with .subscribe{cryptos->displayData(cryptos)}, but getting a compile time issue. I don't know exactly what I am referring to when mentioning cryptos. I thought it was just the model class name with an 's' added(please dont ask why I thought that). The error I'm getting with .subscribe {this::displayData})? is
retrocrypto0827\MainActivity.kt: (42, 25): The expression is unused. I dont think I'm referencing the INTERFACE correctly. Thank you in advance

MainActivity.kt

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import com.example.retrocrypto0827.Adapter.CryptoAdapter
    import com.example.retrocrypto0827.Model.Crypto
    import com.example.retrocrypto0827.RetrofitClient.IMyApi
    import com.example.retrocrypto0827.RetrofitClient.RetrofitClient
    import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
    import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
    import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


        internal lateinit var jsonApi: IMyApi
        internal var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = 
        CompositeDisposable()


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            // Init api
            val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance
            jsonApi = retrofit.create(IMyApi::class.java)

            // View
            recycler_crypto.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recycler_crypto.setHasFixedSize(true)
            fetchData()


        }

        private fun fetchData() {
            compositeDisposable.addAll(jsonApi.getData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe {this::displayData})
        }

        private fun displayData(cryptoList: List<Crypto>) {

            val adapter = CryptoAdapter(this, cryptoList)
            recycler_crypto.adapter = adapter

        }


    }
```

Crypto.kt

```
  data class Crypto(val currency: String, val price: String)
```

RetrofitClient Object class

```
    import retrofit2.Retrofit
    import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
    import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

    object RetrofitClient {

        private var ourInstance: Retrofit?=null


        val instance: Retrofit
        get(){
            if(ourInstance == null){
                ourInstance = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.nomics.com/v1/")

     .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
            return ourInstance!!
        }


    }
```

IMyApi interface

```
    import com.example.retrocrypto0827.Model.Crypto
    import io.reactivex.Observable
    import retrofit2.http.GET

    interface IMyApi {

        @GET("prices?key=yourapikey")
        fun getData(): Observable<List<Crypto>>
    }
```

CryptoAdapter.kt

```
    class CryptoAdapter(internal val context: Context, internal val 
    postList: List<Crypto>)
        :RecyclerView.Adapter<CryptoViewHolder>()
    {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
    CryptoViewHolder {
            var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.retro_coin_card, parent, false)
            return CryptoViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return postList.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CryptoViewHolder, position: 
     Int) {
            holder.txtCurrency.text = 
     postList[position].currency.toString()
            holder.txtPrice.text = postList[position].price.toString()
        }
    }
```

CryptoViewHolder

```
  class CryptoViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) 
  {

            val txtCurrency = itemView.txtCurrency
            val txtPrice = itemView.txtPrice
        }
```

I expect it to display the data from the API that I'm using in the order I have put it in the recyclerview. Just a simple display of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `Consumer` interface:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    /**
     * Consume the given value.
     * @param t the value
     * @throws Exception on error
     */
    void accept(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

`.subscribe {this::displayData}` is equivalent to:

```
.subscribe(
    object : Consumer<List<Crypto>> {
        override fun accept(t: List<Crypto>) {
             ::displayData
        }
    }
)
```

so, `::displayData` , which is the reference to the function is not being used.

Just call `.subscribe { displayData(it) }` instead.

Here goes a nice [post](https://medium.com/tompee/idiomatic-kotlin-higher-order-functions-and-function-types-adb59172796) about it higher-order functions.

Aaaand... just as tip, you can create your `Retrofit` instance as a singleton in a more simpler and idiomatic way by using `by lazy`

```
    object RetrofitClient {

        val instance: Retrofit by lazy {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.nomics.com/v1/")

                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you again. I was able to reorganize everything and read up more on high-order functions and understand a lot more.